# Creating my own SAP dashboard/reporting tool for mobile

Tags: reporting, business-objects

Is it possible to create my own mobile dashboard, reporting tool for SAP? I understand the standard components to be used for this purpose are:

1. Business Objects Enterprise Server XI - this provides reporting functionalities for SAP
2. Business Objects Mobile Server - this connects to Enterprise Server and optimizes reports stored there for mobile devices
3. Mobile Web Browser or Mobile Business Objects Report Client - for viewing the reports

I don't intend to purchase the components mentioned above. I only want to know if it's feasible to build my own solution. I am familiar with BAPI's to retrieve data from SAP. What is the proper approach to build an SAP reporting tool?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the answer you'd expect, but how about **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear)** (used to be called i-net Crystal-Clear)? Since you know the data backend, you can easily attach the report server to it, create reports with the (free!) [report designer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer) provided (which is somewhat like Crystal Reports) and, well, run them.

You can even use your existing Crystal Reports templates, since they are supported by i-net Clear Reports.

Now using the report repository you could even store the reports in a convenient way on the server and - here comes what I think you want most - access them from your mobile device.

There are three ways to do that: use the [iPhone app](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/clearreports/mobile/ios), use the [Android app](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/clearreports/mobile/android) or access the remote interface from e.g. your tablet device. From there you can run whatever report you have in the repository. In your case, with a dashboard: encapsulate all the reports you'd like to have in one report file (using subreports) and there you are.

Disclosure: Yep, I work for the company who made all this ;)

P.S. we're working on even better ways to realize dashboards, so stay tuned.

Comment: Nice to have one of you in the field!